# Bootstrap carousel collapses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I've just got the problem that I've never faced before. So, I've got Bootstrap Carousel on web-site, the problem is that carousel collapses the next slide. It just dissapears. Looked over the code - didn't find any mistakes. Can you help me?
Web-site - http://www.navigator-surgut.ru

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M89k4.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consult the guidelines on crafting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit this post to provide more information so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Looks like _MooTools_ is modify the top margin of the carousel's container element.

Comment: Thanks, I disabled _MooTools_ – worked fo me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like *MooTools* is modifying the top margin of the carousel's container element. Not sure how/why though.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling MooTols worked for me pretty well.